# Java classpath requires all jar names to be given in the classpath environment variables

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, classpath

I have a java program which needs to refer many jars(around 10 jars) to execute it. Currently I have given names of all jars in my classpath variables, and these all jars are in same folder. Is there any way so that, I do not have to give all names of the jars in the classpath variable, like just include the path to these jars. Also if I am running these java program from .bat file, how to set classpath in .bat file.

Please let me know, if there any suggestion on this.

Comment: Instead of adding all jar file names, you can set the classpath to the folder containing your jars.

Comment: In your .bat file you can  build up the classpath into a variable. You can either set the CLASSPATH variable this way or use `java -cp classpathvalue`. You could dynamically build up the class path by listing the contents of the folders

Comment: I have given the path to the jars in classpath variable, like CLASSPATH= C:\Users\workspace1\bin\com\sif\bat; in bat folder all jars are there, but its not working. Can you please show this by an example?

Comment: @echo off
java -cp C:\Users\workspace1\bin;
javac Main.java
java Main                                                                                             pause                                                                                                          When I execute the .bat file written like above. It is showing java help options.

Comment: @AmitGautam, the correct command is something like:
To compile:
`javac -cp first.jar;second.jar Main.java`
To execute:
`java -cp first.jar;second.jar Main` where `Main` is the name of your (already) compiled class

Comment: Standard solution is to put a manifest in your main jar containing the Main-Class and Class-Path entries. It depends on how you build (ant/maven/...) how to do that exactly, but I think you can find that.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the classpath, you should be able to do

```
path/folder/*
```

Also, to set the classpath in a bat file, it is the same as in the command line.

```
javaw -cp "classpath" -jar jarname
```